# RocketDock System Tray Docklet

Tags: windows-7, batch, notification-area, rocketdock

I'm looking for either a download location or a how-to on making an executable that toggles the system tray.

All I need to do is create a small `.exe` or download one that toggles Windows 7's system tray's visibility.

I know one exists for RocketDock, as I used to have it installed (pre-wipe, missed one folder on the backup), but I've scanned through over 100 pages of docklets on the RocketDock website with no success, so I now turn to you.

This will finally allow me to get rid of the taskbar entirely.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking, *specifically*.  Clarify more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, turns out the author had renamed it.

Very much recommended for those trying to do away with the taskbar.
[RocketDock Tray Docklet](http://rocketdock.com/addon/docklets/35659)